# Facebook app oauth dialog error

Tags: facebook, oauth

I've been searching for the answer for days and I haven't been successful so I finally post to ask.

I'm developing a facebook app locally (it says I can develop locally in the guide) and having an issue when trying to authorize the app.

The following is the error msg I get when I direct to http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Error
An error occurred with Footmarker. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Canvas URL & Site URL : http://localhost:8888/app/

I'm using EasyPHP hence port 8888. I tried changing port number to 80(default), 8080(one used in facebook guide) and no success.

I don't know if it's EasyPHP that causes the problem or simply I'm doing something wrong.

This thing drives me crazy. Help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

in this url: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME

You have to set `redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/app` and authorize the localhost domain in your facebook app's settings (in the `App domains` field).

The Site URL & Canvas URL are used to check if the redirect_uri is not set to another URL for security reasons but the standard specify redirect_uri so they've let this parameter.

It's for this kind of error I built [OAuth.io](https://oauth.io). We don't want more developers like you with a headache using OAuth.

using it is really easy:

```
OAuth.popup('facebook', function(err, res) {
    // here, you can use res.access_token to make your API Call
    // or...
    res.get('/me')
       .done(function(data) {
        alert('Hello ' + data.name)
    })
})
```

With this, you can't make mistake with URL anymore :)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use `localhost` in the App Domains field: http://flic.kr/p/kHqiny

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your URL is not on the Internet. It is accessible from your computer only. You need a public URL.

Perhaps you can use [dynDNS free](http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/) to get onto the Net with your application from home.

Or, get a web server connected to the Net to host your App.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

this just because of URL mistake

whatever website url is specified should be correct.

i mentioned website url as http://localhost:3000/ and domain as localhost

but in my browser i was running http://0.0.0.0:3000/ that was the actual problem so i ran server as localhost:3000 now its working fine. Because we mentioned site url as localhost fb will redirect to same, if we r running 0.0.0.0:3000 it will rise error that Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

so becarefull with your website url you have specified in facebook app.
and the url you are running locally both should match

thank you